# Is it legal to sell a tutorial video that tells viewers to use UBUNTU and provides tutorials on installing and using UBUNTU?

Tags: legal

I'm wondering if i can make a UDEMY course that includes the use of ubuntu and teaches how to install ubuntu.

Comment: Probably. We aren't your attorneys, nor are we necessarily qualified to practice law in your locality, nor are we authorized to indemnify you. Best of luck!

Comment: That depends on country, state, province and maybe even city. You haven't said where you are, nor how you plan to sell this, so even if we were all lawyers that knew about your area, we wouldn't be able to help. A website isn't really the place to get legal advice, either.

Comment: O'Reilly sells books about using Ubuntu and Linux in general. I couldn't imagine an online course would be much different. Anyway, maybe you should contact Udemy.

Comment: Copyright of Linux systems typically covers redistribution and/or modifications to them. You're not doing any of that, so my very opinionated opinion is that it's ok

Comment: @Beau Bassett-Audain : Please have a look at the Internet → There are 18 million hits with Google, Ubuntu tutorial ... https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ubuntu+totorial

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, yes, why not? Ubuntu is open-source and has the four freedoms:

- The freedom to run the program as you wish, for any purpose (freedom 0).
- The freedom to study how the program works, and change it so it does your computing as you wish (freedom 1). Access to the source code is a precondition for this.
- The freedom to redistribute copies so you can help your neighbor (freedom 2).
- The freedom to distribute copies of your modified versions to others (freedom 3). By doing this you can give the whole community a chance to benefit from your changes. Access to the source code is a precondition for this.